# removing characters from a string - javascript algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm practicing algorithm problems and am trying to remove given letters from a string in o(n) time.

My attempt below is wrong in a couple of ways:

- the last index in the outputString array is "undefined" and I'm not sure why.
- my output is the right letter, but it's being returned for the length of the original string.

How can I fix these and why are these errors occurring?

```
function removeChars(lettersToDelete, string) {
    var flags = {}; // a hash of letters to delete.
    var outputString = string.split("");
    var lettersToDelete = lettersToDelete.split("");
    var i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < lettersToDelete.length; i++) {
        flags[lettersToDelete[i]] = true;
    }
    console.log(flags);

    for (var j = 0; j < string.length; j++) {
        if (flags[string[j]]) {
            outputString[j++] = string[j];
        }
    }
    console.log(outputString); //[ 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', undefined ]

    return outputString.join(""); // 'aaaa'
}
```

Comment: _If you want_, you can use regex. `var regex = new RegExp("[" + lettersToDelete + "]", 'g'); var outputString = string.replace(regex, '');`

Comment: good to listen someone try to learn   1+

Comment: The way you manipulate `j` doesn't look right to me. Also your `outputString` variable is initialised as an array containing all of the letters from the original input, and you never remove anything from that array. Finally, your if statement condition inside the loop is testing whether to delete the current letter, but shouldn't it be testing whether to *keep* the current letter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function removeChars(lettersToDelete, string) {
        var flags = {}; // a hash of letters to delete.
        var outputString =  []; //string.split("");
        var lettersToDelete = lettersToDelete.split("");
        var i, j;
        for (i = 0; i < lettersToDelete.length; i++) {
            flags[lettersToDelete[i]] = true;
        }
        for (var j = 0; j < string.length; j++) {
            if (!flags[string[j]]) {
                outputString.push( string[j] );
            }
        }
        console.log(outputString);
        return outputString.join(""); // 'aaaa'
    }
    removeChars("itu", "mitul");
```

Comment: It will return "ml" and length of the `outputstring` will be 2